# Dependency Injenction in config.yml

Tags: symfony

I have two services and I want pass my parameter from config.yml

my config.yml

```
parameters:
    MyService.class:      Acme\UserBundle\Services\sendEmail
    MyService.arguments:  @mailer

    NewUserListener.class:  Acme\UserBundle\Event\NewUserListener
    NewUserListener.arguments:  @MyService
```

my service.yml inside bundle

```
services:
MyService:
    class:        %MyService.class%
    arguments:    [%MyService.arguments%]

NewUserListener:
    class: %NewUserListener.class%
    arguments:    [%NewUserListener.arguments%]
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: new.user, method: sendEmailToUsers }
```

I got an error

> You cannot dump a container with parameters that contain references to
>   other services

My Questions are:

- How can I inject my arguments from config.yml?
- Where can i Find the list of "global service" like @mailer ? i don't find in doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't reference a service in a parameter. You should replace `%MyService.arguments%` with `@mailer`.

To find all available services, run `php app/console container:debug`

Comment: thanks for your reply. Then when I use `tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener,` my service is added to Container, and I Can find it in `php app/console container:debug`. And it is available "anywhere", right?

Comment: With `php app/console container:debug` I Can see all services in `dependency injection container`?

Comment: A service is always available everywhere. The tag makes the service a listener, which something completely different

Answer (score 1):

This a bit more complicated!

First, you have to declare your default services like that (I changed all the names in order to be compliant with the Symfony2's conventions):

```
# resources/config/services.yml

services:
    my_own.service.default.class: Acme\UserBundle\Services\sendEmail
    my_own.user_listener.default.class: Acme\UserBundle\Event\NewUserListener

services:
    my_own.service.default:
        class: %my_own.service.default.class%
        arguments: [@mailer]

    my_own.user_listener:
        class: %my_own.user_listener.class%
        arguments: [@my_own.service]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: new.user, method: sendEmailToUsers }
```

We will [define some configuration for your bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/configuration.html) in order to allow to change the used services:

```
namespace My\OwnBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

/**
 * This is the class that validates and merges configuration from your app/config files
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#cookbook-bundles-extension-config-class}
 */
class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('my_own');

        // Here you should define the parameters that are allowed to
        // configure your bundle. See the documentation linked above for
        // more information on that topic.
        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('service')->defaultValue('my_own.service.default')->end()
                ->scalarNode('user_listener')->defaultValue('my_own.user_listener.default')->end()
            ->end();

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

Note that, by default, we use our default services defined above in our bundle.

You now can use the following to change your services (in your `app/config.yml`) for instance:

```
# app/config.yml

my_own:
    service: my_other.service
    user_listener: my_other.user_listener
```

Of course, you can define the services `my_other.service` and `my_other.user_listener` as you want in your bundle or in another bundle.

Now we have to tell how to use this configuration to take the wanted services:

```
namespace My\OwnBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

/**
 * This is the class that loads and manages your bundle configuration
 *
 * To learn more see {@link http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html}
 */
class MyOwnExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        $container->setAlias('my_own.service', $config['service']);
        $container->setAlias('my_own.user_listener', $config['user_listener']);
    }
}
```

Finally, in the rest of your code you have to use the aliased services `my_own.service` and `my_own.user_listener` in your code:

```
// In one of your controller:
$this->container->get('my_own.service');
/* or directly */ $this->get('my_own.service'); // if your controller is a child of the framework bundle class `Controller`.
```

Comment: Thanks! for now it's complicated for me, but in the future, i Will try to do this

Comment: Please notr that it makes *no* sense to do this for bundles that you're not going to reuse

Comment: Learning the dependency injection in Symfony2 can be a little bit hard at the beginning but it allows you to make a more scalable and maintenable code and to participate to the main open source bundles of Symfony2. Here is an interesting [link to learn more about it](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/tags.html).